# OnClick on List

Tags: asp.net, list

I don't want to use ImageButton inside my list. I want to call the OnClick event (from code behind) using  tag. How can I do that?

```
<li><a href="#" class="nav-start">Partner</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="NewPartnerFormBtn" OnClick="NewPartnerFormBtn_Click" runat="server"
                    Text="New" ImageUrl="./Images/new-btn.png" CausesValidation="false" /><br />
            </li>
            <li>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ViewPartnerFormBtn" runat="server" Text="View" OnClick="ViewPartnerFormBtn_Click"
                    ImageUrl="./Images/view-btn.png" CssClass="cancel" CausesValidation="false" /><br />
            </li>
            <li>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="EditPartnerFormBtn" runat="server" Text="Edit" OnClick="EditPartnerFormBtn_Click"
                    ImageUrl="./Images/edit-btn.png" CssClass="cancel" CausesValidation="false" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: You can do something similar to this and use css to design and align them correctly `<asp:LinkButton OnClick="clickEvent"><img src="imgurl"/></asp:LinkButton>`

Comment: No, I don't want to use Images. I just want to use the <a> tag and style the li and a via css.

Comment: use linkbutton without image they render as `a` tag, you can use same styles you are writing for `li` and `a` ex: `li.a {font-sizebold;}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use LinkButtons if you need code-behind supported clicks

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="MyStyleClass" OnClick="MyClickEvent" Text="Link Text If Necessary"> Any tags to link </asp:LinkButton>
   </li>
</ul>
```

LinkButton's will render as a simple anchor tag with server-side events.